# CSS can I give div protection from box shadows from other div?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 siblings divs pagCon and cardCon. The cardCon is big div under that has box shadow property and pagCon is above it, it is a small div and I want it to be white. Everything is working but the color of pagCon is darker because of the box shadow of cardCon. Can I somehow keep the box shadow but remove any influence on pagCon?

```
.paginationContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.projectCardContainer {
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 100rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 5px #aaa;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30rem;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can !
Just add `position: relative` to pagCon.
If it still doesn't work, trying adding `z-index: 1` as well.

Here's the example:

```css
.paginationContainer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.projectCardContainer {
  margin: 1rem 2rem;
  width: 100rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 5px red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30rem;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="paginationContainer"></div>
<div class="projectCardContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem.